# Dynamic scaling laws derivation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, critical-phenomena, scaling

In the book Critical Dynamics by Tauber the following scaling hypotheses are made for the static correlation function and for the characteristic frequency in Fourier space
$$
C(\tau, q) = |q|^{-2+\eta} \hat{C}_{\pm}(q \xi)
$$
$$
\omega_{c}(\tau, q) = |q|^z \hat{C}_{\pm}(q \xi)
$$
Here $\tau$ is the reduced temperature and $\xi$ is the correlation length.
Then at page 99 the following dynamic response function
$$
\chi(\tau,q,\omega) = |q|^{-2+\eta} \hat{\chi}_{\pm}(q \xi, \omega \xi^z/Da_0)
$$
where $D$ and $a_0$ are some "microscopic time and length scales". This response function is introduced as a natural consequence of the previous statements but I have not understood what is the logic behind this generalized scaling hypothesis. I mean, on the basis of which hypotheses should this response function be written in this way?